# Different Result from EXEC sp_executeSQL and Exec in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I know there are many examples on above two methods, but unfortunately, I am not getting any positive result from any. Please help me in given case.

I have created a user filter app for searching data. Once user define the search criteria, it create list of columns and values for all the filter selected by user and create a profile.

When needed user just select this profile and search from given data.

```
DECLARE @FilterID INT = 1, @filtertext VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @filtertext = dbo.GetWhereCriteriaFunction(@FilterID)
    --here @filtertext = 'And Field1 In (ValueList)  And Field2 In (ValueList)  And (Field3 Between 1 And 2 OR Field3 Between 3 And 4) '

DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE ''A''=''A'' + @fText'

-- Method 1
EXEC sp_executeSQL @Filter, N'@fText varchar(max)', @fText = @filtertext

-- Method 2
EXEC ('SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE 1=1' + @filtertext)
```

Outputs:

- Method 1 : 0 rows
- Method 2 : 125 rows

Can someone guide me in above case, why two results defer from each other ?, logically both should return same output

Comment: thank you @marc_s for formatting :) I'll take care next time

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE ''A''=''A'' + @fText'
```

This line concatonates `'A'` with `@fText`. As in, `WHERE 'A' = ('A' + @fText)`.

Comment: can you suggest, how to build properly, I think this is the case I am facing.

Comment: I changed the method to  
<pre><code>`Set @filtertext = '''A'' And Field1 In (ValueList)  And Field2 In (ValueList)  And (Field3 Between 1 And 2 OR Field3 Between 3 And 4) '
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE ''A''= @fText';`  </code></pre>
but still the same result.

Comment: You want `'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE ''A''= @fText'` to be something like `'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE ''A''=' + @fText`. other answers have dealt with this better than mine did. `PRINT @Filter` and you will see what you are actually executing...

Comment: Your suggested method I am already using. which is giving me proper result. But according to SQL documentation, that method is not using already generated plan, it will always create new plan. so, I want the first method. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are dynamically building SQL, and Method 2 is perfectly fine you can do that. 
However, Method 1 is a more restricted version where you can pass in only the parameter values and nothing else (no filedname or any extra keywords).
So with paremeter like this it will work:

```
DECLARE @filtertext NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @filtertext = N' 1 '
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE 1=1 and Field1 = @fText'
EXEC sp_executeSQL 
    @Filter, 
    N'@fText nvarchar(max)', 
    @fText=@filtertext
```

Because you are passing only values.

With the following parameter will not work

```
DECLARE @filtertext NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @filtertext = N' AND Field1 = 1 '
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT 1 FROM Tablename WHERE 1=1 @fText'
EXEC sp_executeSQL 
    @Filter, 
    N'@fText nvarchar(max)', 
    @fText=@filtertext
```

because you are not only passing value - it is containing also Field1 and AND keyword as parts of WHERE statement, and Procedure sp_executeSQL won't allow this.

Comment: The problem is I am/will never be sure about what fields user going to choose for Filter. So, I can't use the method you suggested. The Where string should be build dynamically, and it should be pass as a parameter with "EXEC sp_executeSQL"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of `@filtertext` starts with a blank, the first WHERE clause evaluated to

```
WHERE 'A' = 'A And Field1 In (ValueList)  And Field2 In (ValueList)  And (Field3 Between 1 And 2 OR Field3 Between 3 And 4)'
```

which is obviously false (so the query returns no rows) and for sure it's not what you wanted.

The parameters of the `sp_executeSQL` procedure are meant to provide values for the parameters of the query. They are not meant to replace a part of the query string.

Therefore, the second method is the one you wanted.

Comment: I think the string builds properly as I have 2('') with each A, even let me try with your suggestion and will update you in short.